# C - A veces no se ejecuta una funcion

Tags: c, array, lista, function, struct

Tengo un seudo grafo conformado por listas de adyacencia, donde tree es un arreglo de "lista_t"

```
typedef struct nodo {
  int value;
  struct nodo *next;
} nodo_t;

typedef struct {
  nodo_t *primero;
  nodo_t *ultimo;
  int len;
} lista_t;
```

Bueno y mi problema es que no siempre se ejecuta la función `add_edge()`, inserta correctamente, la funcion se ejecuta correctamente cerca de `100000000` veces.

Pero por ejemplo el arreglo en la posicion `[722606]` , (osea la 722606va lista creada en un comienzo y con un solo nodo) sus primeras 103 inserciones se hacen correctamente, pero al momento de agregar a la lista el valor 106098 mediante `add_edge()` no inserta el elemento, luego la 105va insersión es el 75695, y tampoco lo inserta, así hasta que llega a su ultima inserción el 558624, que lo agrega correctamente.

Por ejemplo la cantidad de inserciones en la posicion `[722606]` es 108, mientras tanto el largo de la lista le faltan valores y su parametro lista->len es igual a 106. (Me genera segmentation faults)

```
  scanf("%d\n",N);
  nodo_t *aux = (nodo_t*)malloc(sizeof(nodo_t));
  aux->value= N;
  aux->next = NULL;      
  for (i=0;i<N;i++)
    add_fedge(&tree[i],aux);
  scanf("%d\n",&M);
  for (i=0;i<M;i++){
    scanf("%d %d\n", &aux1 , &aux2 );
    add_edge(&tree[aux1],aux2);
    add_edge(&tree[aux2],aux1);
    }
```

Hago el malloc correspondiente

```
 scanf("%d\n",&N);
 lista_t* tree = (lista_t*)malloc(N*sizeof(lista_t));
```

Y mis funciones son (estan en otro archivo)

```
extern void add_edge(lista_t *l,int x){
  nodo_t *aux = malloc(sizeof(nodo_t));
  aux->value = x;
  aux->next = l->primero;
  l->primero = aux;
  l->len++;
  }

extern void add_fedge(lista_t *l,nodo_t *aux){
  l->primero = aux;
  l->ultimo = aux;
  l->len = 1;
  }
```

<sub>- Las listas de C++ son algo mas lentas

 - La idea no es hacer comprobaciones ni contar para sacar el largo en caso de error ya que el arreglo es de 1 millon de listas
   aproximadamente, donde cada lista tiene un promedio de 1500 elementos
   (saqué los cálculos)</sub>

Comment: En el primer código aparecen `aux1` y `aux2` que no están declaradas ni creadas... luego empiezas a mezclar índices con valores... no me queda claro el tamaño de la lista cuando te falla (10000000 elementos? 103? 722606?). Por favor explíca mejor el problema y, a ser posible, pon un código de ejemplo que lo reproduzca

Comment: Si, estaba todo declarado pero no lo puse, creo que poner fracciones de codigo así no se da a entender. Bueno reparé el problema de todas formas, reescribiendolo exactamente igual en un archivo en blanco y luego de eso funcionaba correctamente, tal vez el compilador estaba interpretando mal algún espacio mal. (o quien sabe, a veces pasa)

Comment: Seria raro eso que dices, ya que en C el compilador debiese ignorar los espacios en blanco (osea 1 espacio en blanco en C debiese ser lo mismo que 10 espacios en blanco), no asi en otros lenguajes como en Python.